# Display image from json data in html?

Tags: javascript, json, image, toggle

I'm trying to display an image from my JSON data in HTML, but I'm not having any success.

I have a marker which displays some content  when an onclick event occurs.

For this purpose, I am using the following JSON code:

```
var json = {
"Hatch": [
    {
        "image": "img/myimage.jpg",
        "description": "test goes here"
    }
]
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
for( index in json.Hatch )



$('.marker.one').on('click', function(){
$('#show').html(   'Image : ' +json.Hatch[index].image + '| Description : ' + json.Hatch[index].description  );

});
});
```

My trigger on click from my html is the following:

```
<section class="info">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

      <div class="marker one">

         <img  class="trigger" src="img/marker.png">

      </div>

      <div class="marker two">
         <img  class="trigger" src="img/tooltip.png">

      </div>


      </div>
</section>
```

which display here:

```
<div id="show"></div>
```

Any help you may offer would be awesome! I'm starting to use JSON only.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: No `"name"` property appears at `json` variable. Why do you use `for..in` loop?

Comment: im starting with json ...  :/

Comment: What is expected result of `'Price : ' +json.Hatch[index].name`, where no `"name"` property appears at `{
        "image": "img/myimage.jpg",
        "description": "test goes here"
    }`?

Comment: oups my mistake, the image should appear there, i'm updating the code

Comment: I have updated ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for..in` loop is not necessary.  If you are expecting an `<img>` element to be rendered, include `<img>` with `src` set to `json.Hatch[0].image` within string passed to `.html()`

```
$(".marker.one").on("click", function() {
  if (!$("#show img").is("*"))
    $("#show").html(
      "Image : <img src=" + json.Hatch[0].image + ">"
    + "| Description : " + json.Hatch[0].description
    );
});
```

Comment: you are a star ! thank you !

Do you know if there is one instead of having each time the same function to have it loop by ID or something like this ? to make the code shorter as i am going to have like 50 data similar in JSON

Comment: If you have N elements of array and N `.marker` elements, you can use `.index()` to get the index of the element within `.marker` collection, which should correspond to element N within array.

Comment: Hmmm thank you - not sure to understand what you mean by N. do you have any example by any chance ? Really appreciate !

Comment: N being any positive number. Here, N references the number N of `.marker` elements being equal to the number N of elements within array. You can then use `$(".marker").on("click", function() { array[$(this).index()] // do stuff with element of array at $(this).index()})` 0-N, see https://api.jquery.com/index

Comment: Thanks I'll try to give a go !